# How to implement FmDatabase in my iphone application?

Tags: iphone

I want some tutorials or some help from that i can get idea of applying fmdatabase to my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean this?

http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/11/04/simple-sqlite-database-interaction-using-fmdb/